# Is there a benefit to using binary data for an HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, curl, web

Say I have an HTTP POST method that simple echos the request's body and I cURL it like so:

```
curl -X POST -d "test non-binary data" "https://endpoint/path/to/resource"
```

As expected, this will result in the following callback:

```
"test non-binary data"
```

Now let's say I instead pass this data as binary like so:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "test binary data" "https://endpoint/path/to/resource"
```

This will give me the following:

```
"dGVzdCBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YQ=="
```

But I can have my API decode the base64 data and interpret it as ASCII to return the following:

```
"test binary data"
```

As expected, this is the same as the non-binary request. So, with the results being the same, what exactly is the difference between is passing a binary vs a non-binary request body? Are there any benefits to using binary data? If so, what are some examples when I would want to use binary data instead?

Comment: Using a base64 encoding you can embed data in a request that would otherwise collide with the request structure, since it contains control characters use by that structure. Also you can embed an arbitrary set of characters even if the transport layer does not support that at all. So you get the full range of the UTF-8 character set for example which cannot be embedded otherwise without using escape strategies with limited robustness.

Comment: @arkascha Wouldn't you need to do some sort of parsing on the back-end then to actually derive values from the binary data? Seems like either way you have to do some data preparation--only difference is when.

Comment: Certainly, every conversion is an effort. It is a question of robustness and standards. base64 encoding allows to embed arbitrary data even without knowing anything about the transport layer, relay servers, different encoding environments, ... It allows to use the lowest common denominator which is ASCII encoding for arbitrary data.

Comment: @arkascha So there isn't any sort of performance benefit to using binary data?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no. Why should there be? In contrary, as you correctly point out it adds a conversion penalty which often will reduce the performance theoretically.

Comment: @arkascha It's starting to seem like using binary data or not is just a matter of preference.

Comment: No, not at all. It is a question of robustness and keeping standards. Robustness here means: no component in the transport queue fiddles around with the actual data.

Comment: @arkascha I guess I'm not sure what you mean by that. Are you saying that there are some instances where binary data is "standard". If so, when? Also, I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my comments.

Comment: No, but the lowest common denominator I mentioned is in fact a standard you can expect from all components. Without that you need to _hope_ that all components in the transport and processing queue are able to handle the data structure you use. See why I mention robustness? A simple example: sending emails. Do you use 7bit or 8bit encoding? 8bit is more efficient for obvious reasons and _usually_ works just fine. But there still might be some old mail servers that will not be able to handle that...

Comment: @arkascha Aahhhhh okay. Thank you very much this makes much more sense now

Comment: Another good example is morse code: horribly ineffective compared to the spoken word or even high compressed data transmissions, but extremely robust. No matter how bad the reception is, you can still transmit with extremely high precision (low error rate). Though it is slow as unbaked dough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As expected, this is the same as the non-binary request. So, with the results being the same, what exactly is the difference between is passing a binary vs a non-binary request body? Are there any benefits to using binary data? If so, what are some examples when I would want to use binary data instead?

Many questions at once, let's decipher this:

> So, with the results being the same, what exactly is the difference between is passing a binary vs a non-binary request body?

This has been mentioned in the comments and also in answers. The difference is that when not using "binary data" parsing might occur changing the meaning of the data (as raw binary data) to something different, like a file to upload or character encoding of the shell (which might apply as well to binary data but then it being less unexpected).

> Are there any benefits to using binary data?

Yes, it's more expressive. You more correctly say which data you want to transfer under any circumstances (still modifications of option argument based on your shell rule might still apply).

> If so, what are some examples when I would want to use binary data instead?

I'm lazy to provide these, so just do two tests, one with and one without. As you're testing and from your question you're expecting both to be the same. If you encode that expectation in the same test-case, you can add a data-provider and then add regressions when you run over them. These changes will answer your question(s) over time. Point in case is here, that if you can't answer the questiuon and even after feedback from Stackoverflow and other resources, you need to ensure that your expectations are fulfilled, even if these are two at once.

These are your tests. Write them as you understand them. If in error, fix them later. This is what version control is for. If you are in error, your tests will tell you. Use tests for your own needs. That is basically it. You might need to do changes in future as you were wrong. However the tests normally reflect your state of mind at the time you write them. So in this case, your tests should have alreay specified that you don't understand the difference between those two options, so just assert that both do the same thing. Document that by writing your test (but don't skip one option while you think it's the same but you're not really sure it is), and you will write the right test. You can fix tests later if you become aware of a mistake and at that time the change should fully document what you expect should be done. Don't hide your questions, assert the answers wihtin the test instead. A test is easy to run again, so you can easily check what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --data-binary
>
> (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing
>   whatsoever.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a
>   filename. Data is posted in a similar manner as -d, --data does,
>   except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved and
>   conversions are never done.
>
> If this option is used several times, the ones following the first
>   will append data as described in -d, --data.

You should not receive base64 encoded data using the `--data-binary` option. If you do, its not `curl` related.

Straight to the question - the only benefit I see is that curl will not process the data passed. If you *need* to preserve newlines etc it makes sense to use it.

Comment: I am using AWS API Gateway which takes the binary data and base64 encodes it. Even so, the base64 stuff is not what I'm confused about. I'm wondering why I would ever need to use binary data. Even if curl doesn't process the data, it seem unnecessary to pass as binary since you'll just have to parse on the backend

Comment: Indeed you'll need to parse on the backend. In some situations you just need to pass a binary file with curl. Using `--data-binary` you send it 1:1 as the parameter name suggests by itself.

Comment: @hanshenrik I tested on my server, he is right like the man page says, `-d` / `--data` does not preserve new lines if you upload with cURL from a file but `--data-binary` preserves new lines.
By the way, I don't think using `--data-binary` improves the security because it is also possible to inject `@/etc/passwd` with this parameter. When I tested, the file content was received on my server.
You probably meant it is not possible to inject a file with `--data-raw`.

Comment: @baptx sorry, you are correct. i deleted the incorrect comment